# Crossfilter dimension and group to filter out data below certain threshold

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following data, and I am trying to plot 2 bar charts:

- Total units of a given type
- Units of a type less than version 2.0

Where x-axis in both the charts is the type of unit.

The charts are fine. The problem is:

When I select the bar on the 2nd chart I expect to see only units with version < 2.0 in the data table and the 1st chart i.e. one record in this case. But what I get is all the units of that particular type (which is what I expect if I click on a bar in first chart) i.e. 3 records.

See http://jsfiddle.net/y1o52tk4/6/

The problem I guess is with how I group for version chart:

```
var versionGroup = type1Dim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('version_count'));
```

Data:

```
var data = [{
         "version": 1.0,
         "serial": '1A',
         "type": "a"
},{
         "version": 2.0,
         "serial": '2A',
         "type": "a"
},{
         "version": 2.0,
         "serial": '2AA',
         "type": "a"
},{
         "version": 2.0,
         "serial": '2B',
         "type": "b"
},{
         "version": 2.5,
         "serial": '25B',
         "type": "b"
},{
         "version": 1.0,
         "serial": '1B',
         "type": "b"
}];
```

Comment: I guess the more correct, complete way to do this would be to create a dimension which has a composite key of both the version and type, then [pre-filter the data dynamically](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted) to remove everything with version >= 2.0. It's some work, though, maybe only worth it if you have a lot of cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think this approach would work. With composite key and filtering out version < 2.0 something like the following key value pair group will be formed `{[1.0, a]:5, [1.1, a]:4, [1.3, a]:1, [1.0, b]:2, [1.8, b]:1}` . We would then again have to create another group from this with key value pair of type:total units and that leads us back to the original problem.

Comment: You can build the keys however you want, so you could get `{[1.*,  a]: 5, [1.*, b]: 17, [2.*, a]: 3, [2.*, b]: 32}`. The dimension key generation function is as general as you want it to be.

Comment: Yes, it can! But now when I click on a bar in the 2nd chart, zero records get selected. I updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y1o52tk4/7/

Comment: Responded in answer below, although my opinion about composite keys may be unpopular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the comments above, but let's spell it out and clarify a couple of things.

You can use composite keys and then filter the group using a "fake group", as you did in your updated fiddle above, in order to get this effect.  And this is probably the most general and most stable way to do this, without having to do any UI hacks.

The thing to understand about crossfilter keys, however, is that it is always going to coerce them to values.  So if you want a composite key, it's best to just construct it as a string yourself, because if you pass it as a an array, crossfilter will coerce it to a string and give you a join with `,` - which can be made to work, and I am aware that the dc.js scatterplot does this, but I don't recommend it.  It's less efficient than creating the strings yourself (because you will only do it once rather than having it happen inside crossfilter internals), and because you have a lot more control.

Here is a long discussion with Jason Davies which convinced me:
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/pull/48

So here's a string concatenation composite key version of your fiddle.

First the composite key:

```
    var type1Dim = ndx.dimension(function(d){
                            if(d.version<2.0)
                                return '1.' + d.type;
                            else
                                return '2.' + d.type;});
```

(The most foolproof separator would be `'\x0'` but `'.'` works fine here.)

Next, a plain key accessor:

```
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key;})
```

And we let dc.js infer the domain of the ordinal scale too:

```
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal());
```

And it works, but now the ticks have the ugly composite key. To fix that:

```
    versionChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d.split('.')[1];
    });
```

My fork: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/y09cok1z/4/

EDIT: I forgot to update the fake group generator, which happens not to matter here, but for generality, it should split the key as well:

```
function removeVersion2(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.key.split('.')[0] != 2;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you created a custom count of versions less than 2 and plotted that in your bar chart. Crossfilter has no idea what that refers to in the reverse direction. Thus when you click on the second chart in area 'b' crossfilter applies .filter("b") to that dimension and then the crossfilter object. Thus your output is correct. To do what you want to do I would recommend adding a new dimension

```
var versionDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.version});
```

and then add an onfiltered listener to your second chart
This listener checks to see if you tried to filter your second chart and if so applies a filter on the new dimension i created above.

```
.on("filtered", function(chart){
    if(typeDim.top(ndx.size()).length) < ndx.size())
    {
        versionDim.filter(1);
    }else{
        versionDim.filterAll();
    }
})
```

Comment: This is a great solution and much simpler than the composite key solution I expressed above. But what are `filter_is_applied` and `filter_is_removed`?

Comment: Gordon-I cleaned up the event listener, initially i was going to use those variables to compare filters but then realized we only really cared if the second chart was filtered at all and so just checked to see if a filter was in place.