# dc.js: Bar chart on subset of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I have data in format

```
 [
{ "date": dt1, "action": "T", "isRequest": "", "delay": 0 },
{ "date": dt1, "action": "C1", "isRequest": "R", "delay": 10 },
{ "date": dt1, "action": "T", "isRequest": "", "delay": 0 }, 
{ "date": dt1, "action": "C2", "isRequest": "R", "delay": 20 },
{ "date": dt1, "action": "T", "isRequest": "", "delay": 0 },
... ]
```

Main bar chart is about counts (1 line in array), all delays chart is about delay distribution (attribute delay)
Filtering by date main graph, changes data on all delays chart. 

So far, so good. 

Now, I want an another chart that works with subset of data in all delays chart, taking into account filter for attribute "action": "C1". 
I could filter original data and call `crossfilter(filteredData)`, but than filtering on main graph would not reflect on data in this chart. 
I have tried to get inspiration from [Crossfilter dimension and group to filter out data below certain threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107224/crossfilter-dimension-and-group-to-filter-out-data-below-certain-threshold)

Example is on 
http://jsfiddle.net/iracic/dtyeL7g7/5/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to implement a filter in a custom group so that the group only aggregates records that meet your criteria. You can use a helper library like Reductio to do this and would build your group something like:

```
var dim = ndx.dimension(...);
var group = reductio().count(true)
  .filter(function(d) { return d.action === "C1"; })(dim.group());
```

Example in the documentation here: https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-b-filter-b-i-filterfn-i-

It is also possible to do this directly using custom groups, but it's a bit complex.

Unrelated: group.reduceCount doesn't take a parameter, so the functions you are passing to it in your example aren't doing anything.

Comment: I ended with using fake group + key accessor + use of concatenated key. Feel free to comment performancewise vs reductio. Example is based on some your example, if my memory is good... :-)
http://jsfiddle.net/iracic/dtyeL7g7/7
BTW, do you know why UI  selection is not aligned when you use chart.centerBar(true) ?

Comment: Ah, yeah, in this scenario the fake group approach will work. It doesn't work well if you have more complicated criteria where you'd end up needing to combine groups. The performance of the reductio approach should be a little better as you don't need to re-filter the groups every time you want to render an update to the chart, but in this case it's not a big difference.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will close the question "for time being" :-)